# IIS Reverse Proxy to Different Server

Tags: javascript, iis, web-config, reverse-proxy, windows-server

I am trying to figure out if its possible to do a Reverse Proxy in IIS that actually hit a different web server end point. I have used it to traverse Ports on the same machine, but never to a different machine. The purpose of this is that I am writing a Javascript application that needs to connect to data on a different server and I am getting Same Origin errors.

Note: Unfortunately, changing the remote server and service to accept JSONP or CORS is not an option.

Here is the config for Port jumping using IIS Reverse Proxy

```
<system.webServer>      
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Reverse Proxy to Different Port" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^name/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:5984/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: @StevenVondruska Well... I need to find out if its possible to use Reverse Proxy to call a different server ip and if it is, how to do it.

Comment: Do you have [Application Request Routing (AAR)](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) installed in IIS?

Comment: Then what you have written should work. Just change `<action type="Rewrite" url="http://*IP HERE*:*PORT HERE*/{R:1}" />` and then have your Javascript issue a HTTP GET/POST to `/name/*path to remote server*`.

Comment: @StevenVondruska I am copying your answer to an actual answer below.  Please let me know if you would like to answer it yourself and I will remove my answer.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 I put all of the comments into one large answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make this work, you need to have [Application Request Routing (AAR)](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) installed on the IIS server you want to act like the reverse proxy. After that, then add the following into the web.config:

```
<system.webServer>      
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Reverse Proxy to Different Port" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^name/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://[hostname here]:[port number here]/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

This will redirect any request where the path starts with `name/` to the other server. So if you're seeking `/foo/bar` on the remote server, you would need Javascript to request `/name/foo/bar` to the IIS server that has the reverse proxy configured.