# server side rendering is not working in angular universal in iis

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-universal

I referred https://github.com/angular/universal-starter and have implemented in angular5.server side rendering is not working after hosting in iis.It is fine in localhost:4000

Thanks

Comment: and what error do you get !?

Comment: no error.I am running npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr  and checked in  http://localhost:4000.my updated meta tags and other contents are rendering.For hosting I am moving only browser folder files as per above tutorial.Whether I need to run any other command for production

Comment: any update!!!!!

Comment: Can you provide your production URL?

Comment: From what i understand, it's not practical/not easily feisable to serve the static files seperatly from the node/angular server process for the transition to happen properly. What you could do is use a reverse proxy like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16290029/643039) to your port 4000.

Comment: Maybe you should show your IIS config? Also, what do you mean  by 'not working after route navigation' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JavaScriptServices` for `ASP.NET`. It provides:

> **Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates** plugs into dotnet new, providing
>   project templates for Angular 2, Aurelia, Knockout, React, and
>   React+Redux applications. **Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices** is how
>   SpaTemplates-produced projects work internally. It provides useful
>   features for SPA applications, such as server-side rendering for
>   Angular and React applications, plus integration with Webpack build
>   middleware. **Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices** is how SpaServices works
>   internally. It’s a low-level library that gives a fast, robust way for
>   ASP.NET Core applications to run arbitrary JavaScript code on the
>   server.

[TUTORIAL](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/)

[#Server-side-prerendering](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices#server-side-prerendering)

> [aspnetcore-angular2-universal](https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal). After running it,I got Child compilation failed error

@kamalav, I tested it locally.

**Requirements:**
Make sure you have at least Node 6.x or higher (w/ npm 3+) installed!
This repository uses ASP.Net Core 2.0, which has a hard requirement on .NET Core Runtime 2.0.0 and .NET Core SDK 2.0.0. Please install these items from here

1. npm install
2. npm run build:dev
3. dotnet restore
4. dotnet run

Comment: Thanks,But Iam using angular5.I followed this  https://github.com/angular/universal-starter .its working fine in local.pls help me to deply it in iis

Comment: @kamalav, Actual link about it. Look https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/modules/aspnetcore-engine/README.md

Comment: Thanks.I never used asp.net in my app.whether it will be helpful

Comment: @kamalav, https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal. Configured project iis hosted with SSR using angular-cli

Comment: Thanks.I will try

Comment: Hi,I downloaded your project and have run npm install .After running it,I got Child compilation failed error.

Comment: @kamalav, which project? post the link, I will check it

Comment: which link?.I am not getting. Whether your project (https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal)  or mine

Comment: Hi,Thanks,If u help to host angular universal starter project( which I  already done) in iis will be more useful for me.Because there is no enough time for me to complete the project.Your project is totally new for me

Comment: ,Thanks. I am using your project .You updated meta in app.module for each route I need to update it after getting api response.How can i implement it while defining route.I am updating meta in each component using meta service,whether it is ok

Comment: @kamalav, it's not my project. I just reference it as possible solution for your case.https://github.com/MarkPieszak he can help you with this project

Comment: ok.thanks .can you pls help me to fix  "Http 404 error while giving url like .vpf and refereshing the page" error.It doesn't hit my app

Comment: how can i use keyboardEvent in this project.it gives keyboardEvent not defined error while using keyboardevent with hostlistener.

Comment: I used like that its working fine in angular.But not in this project.getting error as keyboardevent is not working

Comment: @kamalav, in local? I can look it later

Comment: I used sw precache and service worker in my project after integrating my project with this.its not working.

Comment: for offline caching.whether i need to cache only cilentapp folder or views also

Comment: @HostListener('document:keypress', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event) {
    console.log(event);
    let x = event.keyCode;
    if (x === 27) {
      console.log('Escape!');
    }
  }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168383/discussion-between-yerkon-and-kamalav).